# Remove file in form if constraint violation

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm followed the tutorial to manage the upload of multiple files http://growingcookies.com/easy-multiple-file-upload-in-symfony-using-the-collectiontype-field/

The system for uploading multiple files works fine.

I added a constraint to allow only certain types of files and to set a maximum size.

When this constraint is enabled, the uploaded files are still present in the form but they are actually delete.

The javascript code always displays the files as present when in fact they are no longer present :

[image]

The buttons to delete the files are still present ..
Do you know how I can completely delete the form files in case of a constraint violation while displaying the error message ? Or do you have a better way to upload multiple files with constraints in Symfony 4 ?

### My twig :

```
{% extends '@Ticketing/base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ 'New Ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}{% endblock %}
{% block header %}<h1>{{ 'New Ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}</h1>{% endblock %}

{% block form_group_class -%}
    col-sm-8
{%- endblock form_group_class %}


{% block main %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' _self %}

    <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">{{ 'Create a new ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}</h3>
        </div>

        {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' _self %}

        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'} }) }}
        <div class="box-body">

            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

            <div id="filesProto" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.documents.vars.prototype)|e }}"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="ticket_form_documents">Pièce-jointe</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8" id="filesBox">
                    {% set pos = 0 %}
                    {% for doc in form.documents %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-xs-1" id="jsRemove{{ pos }}" style="">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFile($(this));"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-xs-11" id="jsPreview{{ pos }}">{{ doc.vars.value.name }}</div>

                            <div style="display:none">
                                {{ form_widget(doc) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {% set pos = pos + 1 %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->

        <div class="box-footer">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8">

                <button id="dropbutton" class="btn bg-ticketing btn-flat form-control" type="submit">
                    {{ 'Submit the ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}
                </button>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer -->
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>

    <script>
        var fileCount = '{{ form.documents|length }}';
        var removeButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onclick='removeFile($(this));'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>";
        function removeFile(ob)
        {
            ob.parent().parent().remove();
        }
        function createAddFile(fileCount)
        {
            // grab the prototype template
            var newWidget = $("#filesProto").attr('data-prototype');
            // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
            newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, fileCount);
            newWidget = "<div style='display:none'>" + newWidget + "</div>";
            hideStuff = "";
            hideStuff += "<div class='col col-xs-1' id='jsRemove" + fileCount + "' style='display: none;'>";
            hideStuff += removeButton;
            hideStuff += "</div>";
            hideStuff += "<div class='col col-xs-11' id='jsPreview" + fileCount + "'>";
            hideStuff += "</div>";
            hideStuff += "<div class='col-sm-8'>";
            hideStuff += "<button type='button' id='jsBtnUpload" + fileCount + "' class='btn btn-default'>";
            hideStuff += "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> {{ 'Pièce-jointe' | trans }}";
            hideStuff += "</button>";
            hideStuff += "</div>";
            $("#filesBox").append("<div class='form-group'>" + hideStuff + newWidget + "</div>");
            // On click => Simulate file behaviour
            $("#jsBtnUpload" + fileCount).on('click', function(e){
                $('#ticket_form_documents_' + fileCount + '_file').trigger('click');
            });
            // Once the file is added
            $('#ticket_form_documents_' + fileCount + '_file').on('change', function() {
                // Show its name
                fileName = $(this).prop('files')[0].name;
                $("#jsPreview" + fileCount).append(fileName);
                // Hide the add file button
                $("#jsBtnUpload" + fileCount).hide();
                // Show the remove file button
                $("#jsRemove" + fileCount).show();
                // Create another instance of add file button and company
                createAddFile(parseInt(fileCount)+1);
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            createAddFile(fileCount);
            fileCount++;
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

The code is available here: https://github.com/oanalivia/Multiple-File-Upload-in-Symfony-using-the-CollectionType-Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one banale solution would be to adapt the output and just filter the docs out, that don't have a value.

```
                {% for doc in form.documents %}
                    {% if doc.vars.value %} {### <-- new 1/2 ###}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-xs-1" id="jsRemove{{ pos }}" style="">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFile($(this));"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-xs-11" id="jsPreview{{ pos }}">{{ doc.vars.value.name }}</div>

                        <div style="display:none">
                            {{ form_widget(doc) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% set pos = pos + 1 %}
                    {% endif %}  {### <-- new 2/2 ###}
                {% endfor %}
```

if you're using a fairly new version of twig (>= 2.10, I believe), you can also only modify the first line of that section:

```
{% for doc in form.documents|filter(doc => doc.vars.value) %}
```